# PHP syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and have tried to figure out what the problem is with this code I am using. It's my first MySQL query and it appears to be choking on the last line, throwing "syntax error, unexpected $end". I tried using endwhile instead of } that didn't solve it so I'm stumped. The ending ?> tag does seem to match the starting php tag so not sure what is missing. Here it is:

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("ratetable.db.1018.host.com", "ratetable","notmypassword") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("rates");
$term = (int)$_POST['term'];
$sql = mysql_query("select * from 'rates' where 'mileage' <= 'term';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo '<br/> Mileage radius:'.$row[mileage];
    echo '<br/> Rate per mile:'.$row[ratepermile];
    echo '<br/><br/>';
}
?>
```

I saw one post where someone enabled short tags to on in php.ini and I added that as a precaution (wasn't already there) but didn't do anything. I'm drawing a blank about why it's not liking the last line.

Thank you for having a look.

Comment: You're missing a `")`, even SO's code highlighting is showing you that

Comment: don't use a mysql_query or similar. Use PDO or mysqli

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: As others have mentioned, you're missing a closing " and ) . But you're new and we all make these mistakes! The php error can be misleading as you look to the end, but it happens to all of us! Good luck learning php going forward and take the advice about learning PDO or MySQLi

Comment: See where the syntax highlighting breaks? That's where your error is. That's about 50% of the reason why people like using editors with syntax highlighting.

Comment: @njk - Thanks. One question though - I see the mysql environment GoDaddy has is 5.0 - I just read that PDO is as of 5.5. So can I use PDO in my case?

Comment: @Sammitch - I'm not sure what you mean. I'm only using GoDaddy's FTP file manager to do this so there's zero checking...it's practically like using wordpad.

Comment: @Shawn You can run a `phpinfo();` to see if the `PDO` driver is installed.

Comment: @njk...well I'll be dipped! Yep, it appears to be enabled in mysql5.0. Yes, I'm learning from online tutorials. Guess I'll have to learn what PDO is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't close the bracket after your query.

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from 'rates' where 'mileage' <= 'term'");
```

Comment: Just closed it. Still got the same thing on the last line. Thanks for noticing that! :) (mental note: don't code after a blood test lol!)

Comment: lol -2 for this somehow even though it was the first answer.

Comment: Yeah I've had that after donating blood. Just take it easy!

Answer (score 4):

The following line:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from 'rates' where 'mileage' <= 'term';
```

needs to change to:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from 'rates' where 'mileage' <= 'term'");
```

Comment: Upvotes. Many, many upvotes.

Comment: You should probably advise OP to stop using `mysql_` functions

Comment: True, but it had already been added as a comment to his question above.

Comment: OK that's what I missed. Now I'm getting mysql_fetch_array() expects "parameter 1 to be resource, boolean" on the line with the while statement.

Comment: @njk - I'm new to mysql - I'm not sure what you mean. I use GoDaddy and it looks like they use mysql5.0 - I just checked something regarding what you said and it said it's deprecated as of 5.5, which I don't have.

Comment: @Shawn your SQL statement is also broken. Single quotes and backticks are completely different. Single quotes enclose strings, backticks [optionally] enclose table and field names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're following some online tutorials, but you need to be careful about the date and reputation of the tutorials you use.  Those functions are about to be deprecated in favor of [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).  It's almost the same syntax, but allows you to prepare your statements first to protect against injection attacks.  Also, you should take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), since it does the same thing but allows you to use different database types.  As a beginner, that's extremely unlikely, but it's still very important to be familiar with.

Finally, I would suggest a good editor like [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) that gives you syntax and error highlighting, so you're less likely to make a mistake like this in the future.

Above all, please, read the [PHP Manual!](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php).  It's the single greatest resource for a PHP developer, and if you had looked at that instead of some old tutorial, you would have discovered that mysql_* is no longer recommended.

Comment: Thanks Chris. You are correct. Since I'm like totally brand new to PHP, I am not aware of this PDO stuff and I see it's a little like how Windows started doing db connection statements when I think of it.